# self hosted Analytics tool for AIR Applications?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, google-analytics, analytics

We are developping an AIR Application that is used within our company VPN. The clients are not always connected to the network while they are in use (there are desktop clients as well as iOS clients). Now we want to add analytics functionality to get statistics of number of installations, frequency of use of certain features and so on.

Because the clients are not always connected to the network, the solution should feature offline tracking of events, which are then sent to the tracking server once a connection to the server can be established.

AppAnalytics (http://www.appanalyticshq.com/features/) offers exactly what we need, but it aparently it's not self-hosted. Because of strict security policies, the clients in our VPN are not allowed to up or download anything to/from the internet - therefore we look for something that can be hosted on a server within our VPN.

Does anyone know a good solution for this scenario?